# Ionic3: Google sign in integration

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am trying to login with google in ionic by following this link-https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-plus/ but not able to get a solution.
I have done following steps for it-

1. created developer account
2. added install the cordova plugin by adding REVERSED_CLIENT_ID
3. added googlePlus to add.module.ts
4. It redirect to google but shows the error page as
5. That’s an error.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The JavaScript origin in the request, http://localhost:8100, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/789162983288-8gf70vepdmiqr1jnr244p183inpn02en.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=789162983288 to update the authorized JavaScript origins.

Please give me solution, if any.Thanks in advance.